# Define a S3 function using UseMethod

Tags: r

I am new to the programming R. I defined a function called liw.mstreeClass and I defined as below, but when I run the program I am keep getting the following errors:

```
# define method: lcosts(generic dispatch)

liw.mstreeClass <- function(nb, data, method, p) UseMethod("nbcosts"){
Error: unexpected '{' in "liw.mstreeClass <- function(nb, data, method, p) UseMethod("nbcosts"){"

if(method=="penrose") { liw <- mat2listw(penroseDis.mstreeClass((scale(data))))
                       return(liw)}
Error: object 'method' not found
}
Error: unexpected '}' in " }"
```

Comment: Please study the documentation. You obviously haven't understood how the S3 system works.

Answer (score 2):

```
# liw.mstreeClass <- function(nb, data, method, p) UseMethod("nbcosts"){
# Error: unexpected '{' in "liw.mstreeClass <- function(nb, data, method, p)
```

Well, to start with, you've got a syntax error here. You can group several expressions with curly brackets but not start curly brackets *after* an expression.

Compare...

```
mean(1)
```

... with ...

```
mean(1){
# error!!
```

Secondly, in S3 you define methods for already existing generic functions. So if you have a function "liw" that could be applied to several classes, then liw.mstreeClass would define the way to do the "liw" for a class called "mstreeClass". So you first have to define liw as a generic function:

```
liw<-function(x,...){
UseMethod("liw")
}
```

Notice that you must have "liw" as an argument to UseMethod, not some random crap. (Take a look at the manual to understand why.) You would rarely have a lot of code besides the call to UseMethod in a generic  function's body.

And having done that, you can define an mstreeClass method for liw. For example,

```
liw.mstreeClass<-function(x, y, z){
   paste("liw equals ", x + y + z)
   }
```

Note that as method dispatch in S3 is based on the first argument, your x must have class "mstreeClass" - only in that case, liw(x) will be directed to liw.mstreeClass(x). And I think if your generic has x as the first argument then the first argument of all methods must be called x too.

```
UseMethod("nbcosts"){"

if(method=="penrose") { liw <- mat2listw(penroseDis.mstreeClass((scale(data))))
                       return(liw)}
Error: object 'method' not found
}
Error: unexpected '}' in " }"
```

Umm.. sorry, these lines don't make a lot of sense. See above or the manuals on how to use UseMethod.